# Core data - Collection NSCFSet was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I'm stuck on a problem while inserting data. I am checking the condition if data not exist then insert but app crashes on

```
BOOL isExist = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

with error Collection `__NSCFSet` was mutated while being enumerated.

but there are simultaneously more operations are running on background threads. which is going to do more operation with core data.

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    NSError *error;
    for (StreamData *stream in streamData) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:DB_TABLE_STREAM];
        [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stream_id = %@", stream.messageId]];
        [request setFetchLimit:1];
        BOOL isExist = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if (!isExist) {
            CF_Stream *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:DB_TABLE_STREAM inManagedObjectContext:context];
            [object setStream_id:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[stream.messageId longLongValue]]];
            [object setType:stream.streamType];
            [object setTime_stamp:[[DateTimeManager sharedInstances] getStreamDate:stream.streamTime]];
        }
    }
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to sve - error: %@", error);
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First off, be aware that there could be race conditions when several threads access your data while you read it. You might not read what you wanted to read.

A quick way to solve your problem should be to iterate `streamData` not using `for each`, but using a standard `for` iterator with indices. That said, you still have to be aware that `streamData` might be changed while you iterate through it, so you need to add checks.

There might be better ways though. Maybe you can avoid this iteration all together.

Comment: Moreover, the approach you're using may not work as you expect. Two threads may write data simultaneously and until [context save:&error] is called this data remains uncommitted so other thread will not get this data when try to perform NSFetchRequest.